# StarFive VisionFive 2 cannot get Ubuntu 23.10 to boot

Tags: boot, server, 23.10

i am trying to install the new ubuntu 23.10 server image for my visionfive 2 and i had debian installed previously and that worked. Now i downloaded the live installer from here https://ubuntu.com/download/risc-v, flashed that file to an sd card using balena etcher (i am running on windows) and tried to boot.
The sbc boots, but i only get errors and it ends up in the u-boot cli:
[image]
[image]
[image]

As a side note, i have added an nvme drive, but that is completly empty and the result is the same, when i try to boot without that nvme. Also the dip switches are in the default position, which should work

Anyone got an idea why this does not work?

Edit:
This is the output without the nvme:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into this - I had a working Debian install, but couldn't boot Ubuntu 23.10.  You have to follow the steps under "Updating U-Boot".

> As both for with some vendor U-Boot releases as well as with the
> upstream U-Boot v2023.10 we found some issues we have prebuilt a
> binary package u-boot-starfive available in
> ppa:ubuntu-risc-v-team/release.

I extracted the two files, ran flashcp from the Debian install, and then I was able to boot Ubuntu 23.10.  Don't forget this step:

> After updating U-Boot it is necessary to reset the environment to the
> defaults. At the U-Boot console you can use the following commands:
>
> env default -f -a
> env save